# UITableView not properly populating sections with NSArray contents

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, json, uitableview

My Parse cloud code sends back JSON to my iOS app with the following structure:

[image]

What I want to do is iterate through this and create a new section in the UITableView for every object in this `matchCenterArray`.

In this instance, there are three objects in the array, each contains a `Top 3` NSDictionary whose value is an array of 3 items, each of which is yet another array of properties. As you can see, I want it set up so that each section has 3 cells, one for each of the top 3 items of that respective `matchCenterArray` object. I then want it to pull the properties of each item and display it in each cell as the `texLabel`, `detailTextLabel`, and thumbnail.

I've tried using a for loop as a solution, but this displays the same item in all cells of the array. This is probably because I'm only looping through matchCenterArray objects, but not additionally looping through items in those objects, as can be seen here:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[[[_matchCenterArray  objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Top 3"] objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"Title"];
```

What I was thinking of doing is nesting a for loop within this one, in place of `objectAtIndex:0`, but sending a message to a for loop doesn't work.

MatchCenterViewController.m:

```
#import "MatchCenterViewController.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MatchCenterViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *matchCenter;
@end

@implementation MatchCenterViewController


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.matchCenter = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle];
    self.matchCenter.frame = CGRectMake(0,50,320,self.view.frame.size.height-100);
    _matchCenter.dataSource = self;
    _matchCenter.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.matchCenter];

    _matchCenterArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.matchCenterArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];

    [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"MatchCenterTest"
                       withParameters:@{
                                        @"test": @"Hi",
                                        }
                                block:^(NSArray *result, NSError *error) {

                                    if (!error) {
                                        _matchCenterArray = result;
                                        [_matchCenter reloadData];

                                        NSLog(@"Result: '%@'", result);
                                    }
                                }];
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return _matchCenterArray.count;
}

//the part where i setup sections and the deleting of said sections

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 21.0f;
}



- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 21)];
    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

//    _searchTerm = [[self.matchCenterArray firstObject] objectForKey:@"Search Term"];

    UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 0, 250, 21)];
//    headerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", searchTerm];
//    headerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
//    headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [headerView addSubview:headerLabel];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.tag = section + 1000;
    button.frame = CGRectMake(300, 2, 17, 17);
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"xbutton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [headerView addSubview:button];
    return headerView;
}



- (IBAction)deleteButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSLog(@"Search Term: '%@'", _searchTerm);

    [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"deleteFromMatchCenter"
                       withParameters:@{
                                        @"searchTerm": _searchTerm,
                                       }
                                block:^(NSDictionary *result, NSError *error) {

                                    if (!error) {
                                        NSLog(@"Result: '%@'", result);
                                    }
                                }];
}




- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     return 3;
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Initialize cell
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        // if no cell could be dequeued create a new one
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }






    for (int i = 0; i<[_matchCenterArray count]; i++) {


    // populate dictionary with results

    //NSDictionary *matchCenterDictionary= [_matchCenterArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // title of the item
    cell.textLabel.text = [[[[_matchCenterArray  objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Top 3"] objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"Title"];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];

    // price of the item
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@", [[[[_matchCenterArray  objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Top 3"] objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"Price"]];
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0f green:127/255.0f blue:31/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

    // image of the item
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[[[_matchCenterArray  objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Top 3"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Image URL"]]];
    [[cell imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];
    //imageView.frame = CGRectMake(45.0,10.0,10,10);



    }

    return cell;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

Comment: Are you using storyboard? Also, it does not look like in cellForRowAtIndexPath that you are iterating though the matchCenterArray again. Shouldn't it be a different array? the matchCenterArray is what you are using to create the sections. That is maybe why it is showing the same object

Comment: I'm using storyboard in general, but not to create the `UITableView`, thats being done programmatically. Yeah, that's what I cant figure out, I was thinking of putting another for loop in there, but I'm not sure how to write the syntax that would send a message to a for loop.

Comment: what do you mean send a message to a for loop? Can you not just iterate through the array in your dictionary? If you can, update your answer with a little more detail.

Comment: I've updated my question to explain what I mean.

Comment: I still don't understand the send message to for loop thing. I would pull everything apart for each cell. So create a new dictionary instance for each position in the _matchCenterArray and then create a new Array that matches he key in the dictionary for what you want, and then load the label values out of the new array. Every cell you will have new objects that will simplify your traversing. You can nest for loops and just spit out the cell in the inner most loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about the loops, the delegate method already run on a loop where the iteration number is equal to the datasource count.

**numberOfSectionsInTableView**

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return _matchCenterArray.count;
}
```

**numberOfRowsInSection**

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
                                   numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
     return _matchCenterArray[section][@"Top 3"].count;
}
```

**cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
                           cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    // Initialize cell
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        // if no cell could be dequeued create a new one
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
                                                         reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // title of the item
    cell.textLabel.text = _matchCenterArray[indexPath.section][@"Top 3"][indexPath.row][@"Title"];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];

    // price of the item
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@", _matchCenterArray[indexPath.section][@"Top 3"][indexPath.row][@"Price"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0f green:127/255.0f blue:31/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

    // image of the item
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_matchCenterArray[indexPath.section][@"Top 3"][indexPath.row][@"Image URL"]]];
    [[cell imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];

    return cell;

}
```

- Don't harcode  your array count, if your json changes, your code will need to change.
- In the future you should look into loading the images asynchronously using a library like [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) in order to avoid lags.

Answer (score 0):

`cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called once per `numberOfRowsInSection:`

You need to add `numberOfSections` as well:

it should look like this:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 3;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Initialize cell
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        // if no cell could be dequeued create a new one
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // the following will set the cell attributes for cells in each section
    // to customize per section, use indexPath.section to get which section you are at

    // title of the item
    cell.textLabel.text = [[[[_matchCenterArray  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row objectForKey:@"Top 3"] objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"Title"];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];

    // price of the item
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@", [[[[_matchCenterArray  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Top 3"] objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"Price"]];
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0f green:127/255.0f blue:31/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

    // image of the item
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[[[_matchCenterArray  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Top 3"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Image URL"]]];
    [[cell imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];

    return cell;
}
```

Please refer to [apple's tableView guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/ManageSelections/ManageSelections.html)